# How to write a complex symmetric gaussian signal

Tags: noise, gaussian, complex, probability-distribution-function

In my work I need to use this signal of complex symmetric gaussian noise signal represented as $w$. But I don't know exactly how to represent it

Comment: Parveen, please clarify what your problem is. In the title you ask "how to write a complex gaussian signal". In your question, you mention "need to use", "represent", "solve" and "simplify".

Answer (score 1):

just generate two independent gaussian random numbers (with a good generator like the Twister) having zero mean and identical variance, call one the real part and call the other the imaginary part.

Comment: Generation I know I want how to represent it numerically

Comment: as pairs of real numbers?

Comment: Can you solve once what you are saying